# Can this be done faster, looking for someone that can show me how it can be done much faster

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance

**PROBLEM:**

**Given two arrays of fixed size:**

```
d_D = (unsigned int*)malloc(50 * 6 * sizeof(unsigned int));

C = (unsigned int*)malloc(1 * 6 * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

**OBJECTIVE:**

**Print all the numbers from array C, only if each row of array d_D have at least one number in common with array C**.

**E.G. first row of d_D {1,8,10,15,20,30}, numbers of array C {1,2,3,4,5,6}, they have number 1 in common, so passed the test.** **This check is done fifty times and has to pass fifty times in order for the number of array C to be printed.**

**Looking for a faster way to do that, than the code provided does.**

**The code provided, is an intersection between each row of the first array and the only row of the second array. The intersection is done fifty time and, if each of the fifty intersections returns a common number, it will prints the six numbers of the second array. The heart of the whole program, is the loop which compare each number of each row of the first array, against each number of the only row of the second array, so even without the printf of the six numbers, and the break instead of the goto to the label notfound, the loop will still be doing an intersection. Also the code is called fifty millions times**

I tried a combination of single arrays and multidimensional array, and it turn out that multidimensional arrays are faster.

**This is what I come up with as the fastest way:** LINK TO THE WHOLE PROGRAM TO BENCHMARK AGAINS: https://onlinegdb.com/B159y4vcQ

**You can go to the above link and add your version, time it to see if you can do better.**

```
        // Iterate through all the rows of array d_D: 1 to 50
        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
        {
             // Compare the first number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 0]))
             {
              goto NextFilter;
             }
             // Compare the second number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i 
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 1]))
             {
              goto NextFilter;
             }
             // Compare the third number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 2]))
             {
              goto NextFilter;
             }
             // Compare the fourth number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 3]))
             {
              goto NextFilter;
             }
             // Compare the fifth number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i 
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 4]))
             {
               goto NextFilter;
             }
             // Compare the sixth number of array C against all the numbers of array d_D row i
             if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 5]))
             {
               goto NextFilter;
             }
             goto notfound;
        NextFilter:
           ;
        }
        // Print the six numbers of array C if all the rows of array d_D have at least one number in common with array C
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", C[0 * 6 + 0], C[0 * 6 + 1], C[0 * 6 + 2], C[0 * 6 + 3], C[0 * 6 + 4], C[0 * 6 + 5]);
 notfound:
 ;
```

**This is another way of doing the same thing, but it takes double the time:**
https://onlinegdb.com/rk97kq_9Q

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{

   unsigned int i0 = 0, j0 = 0; 
   while (i0 < 6 && j0 < 6) 
   { 
     if (d_D[i * 6 + i0] < C[0 * 6 + j0]) 
        i0++; 
     else if (C[0 * 6 + j0] < d_D[i * 6 + i0]) 
        j0++; 
     else // if equal 
     { 
        goto NextFilter;  
     } 
   } 
   goto notfound;
 NextFilter:
 ;
}
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", C[0 * 6 + 0], C[0 * 6 + 1], C[0 * 6 + 2], C[0 * 6 + 3], C[0 * 6 + 4], C[0 * 6 + 5]);
notfound:
;
```

P.S. The reason for the GOTOs is that I am unrolling the loop for cuda implementation, so continue is not an option, but here, I have to loop otherwise the code will be too long.

Comment: It might be quicker if the unnecessary 2D array `C[1][6]` is the 1D array `C[6]` although the complier might optimise. Anyway `d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[1]` is rubbish. You can't compare a whole array like that, and `C[1]` breaks the array bounds too.

Comment: sorry made a mistake, actually is C[0],C[1],C[2],C[3],C[4],C[5] or C[0 * 6 + 0], C[0 * 6 + 1] and so on

Comment: Let the compiler do the optimisation. Your narrative `C[1][6]` does not match the code (now edited). Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Anyway `else` is better than `goto`.

Comment: else will not  make any difference in speed.

Comment: I mean better from a language point of view. Only use `goto` as a last resort to fix a poor algorithm.

Comment: well I do not mind spaghetti code as long as is the fastest way possible

Comment: Fastest make little sense unless the code is called repeatedly.  If call often, are the  2D array and 1D array always the same size?  What are possible array sizes?  If the one dimension of the 2d array matching the 1D? Does the 1D array values  not change yet the other 2D array values do not? Or visa-versa?  What is the range of values - full `int range? To get _fastest_ code, these questions need answering as the approach changes.  Without more info, this post is too broad.  Even better, post a test harness of your code where others can plug their code in and compare times.

Comment: Another speed criteria: likely-hood. If the criteria is likely to be match, then  fast code is written one way. If the criteria is not likely to be match, code  is written another way. The slowest way does not take advantage of probability.

Comment: What is the range of values in array C?

Comment: What is the target architecture? What compiler are you using? Have you run a profiler over the code? There is no one way to express the algorithm that is optimal in all cases.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "Yes." If you need a more detailed answer, then you need to add more detail to the question.

Comment: @chux,@user3386109,@jwdonahue: the 2D array and 1D array are always the same size, range of values 1-59,  target architecture x64 all and compiler icc, cl, nvcc (cuda implementation)

Comment: Repeating the loop 50 million times with the same set of 50 rows, biasses the timing because of loop prediction hardware that may artificially speed up the loop for the specific data distribution you are testing, especially if the matching element is always the first one of each row (cf  https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/WiIlIrsio8 ), or if the first row always fails the test (as in  https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/MIVMvDDJHw )

Comment: Yes, that is true, but this is not about my code, but someone code that outperform my code using the same bias.

Comment: *"I am not asking to optimize my code , but to come up with your faster version."* - Say what?

Answer (score 2):

> Looking for the fastest way possible.

Well, it's nearly impossible to look at C code and judge the performance. Modern compilers are very good at optimizing the code to make it run fast. Besides the compiler optimization there are various tricks played in the hardware (e.g. branch prediction and influence of cache miss/hit, etc.). Stuff that makes it hard to predict performance.

One way to see this is if you compile your code with maximum optimization and try to single step it (or look into the generated machine code). You'll most likely not even be able to understand it because the optimization have turned it into some you just can't recognize... (not just you but all of us...). Turned into "some strange code" that actually do what you want - very efficiently...

So the best advice is: **Write your code so that it's simple to understand** then let the compiler optimize. Then profile the code to see if you have performance problems.

Comment: I would add another advice - it it is possible try to avoid branches as branches flush the pipeline. Sometimes couple of instuctions more, but no branches is more efficient than the very compact code but with branches

Comment: @P__J__: That's correct, but not all tests produce branches and thanks to branch prediction and speculative execution, branches do not necessarily flush the pipeline anymore... Carefully benchmarking the code on the target system with meaningful data is always required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work: the `for` loop does nothing, so a good compiler will just remove it and the only thing you end up benchmarking is the initialization and the `printf`.

Here is reformated version of your complete code with separate timings to support my point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS  5000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    int *d_D, *C;

    d_D = (int*)malloc(ROWS * 6 * sizeof(int));
    C = (int*)malloc(1 * 6 * sizeof(int));

    C[0 * 6 + 0] = 1;
    C[0 * 6 + 1] = 2;
    C[0 * 6 + 2] = 3;
    C[0 * 6 + 3] = 4;
    C[0 * 6 + 4] = 5;
    C[0 * 6 + 5] = 6;

    // make sure that there is a 1 to 6 in each row
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        d_D[i * 6 + 0] = (rand() % 6) + 1;

    // Put other random number in the rest of the array d_D
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
            d_D[i * 6 + j] = (rand() % ROWS) + 1;

    clock_t stop1 = clock();

    /* Check if all rows in d_D contain at least one number from array C.
       loop index `i` should have function body scope to allow testing 
       after the loop exits.
     */
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 0]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 0])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 1])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 2])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 3])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 4])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) ||
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0 * 6 + 5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0 * 6 + 5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        break;
    NextFilter:
        ;
    }
    clock_t stop2 = clock();

    /* In the code posted, this line is always executed.
       Probably not the intended behavior.
       There is a missing test `if (i == ROWS)`
     */
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
           C[0 * 6 + 0], C[0 * 6 + 1], C[0 * 6 + 2],
           C[0 * 6 + 3], C[0 * 6 + 4], C[0 * 6 + 5]);

    clock_t stop = clock();
    printf("Time elapsed in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Init time in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop1 - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Scan time in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop2 - stop1) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (compiled with clang -O3 on OS/X):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Time elapsed in ms: 218.076000
Init time in ms: 218.010000
Scan time in ms: 0.003000
```

If the problem statement is **"given two arrays [...] print all the numbers from array C, only if each row of array d_D have at least one number in common with array C".**, Your code is not consistent with the problem as it prints the contents of `C` unconditionally.

Furthermore, since the main loop has no side effects, it might be optimized out by the compiler and the timings indicate that it does not contribute at all to the elapsed time (`Scan time in ms: 0.003000`).

Comment: I disagree, because I tested it in several compilers and also on gpu and does what is should do. If you check  the link and run, you will see that it print 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: What do you mean my for loop does nothing? Which one?

Comment: Why is so difficult to understand? Do not look at the code, look at the problem and come up with the fastest way to tackle it, is that hard?

Comment: what the loop does is to go from 0 to 49 to compare each number of each row of the first array with each number of the only row of the second array, array C.

Comment: @Mark: The timings show that the `for` loop that scans rows in the `d_C` array and compares elements to those of the `C` array takes very little time, either because it breaks immediately or because it is optimized out. The contents of the `C` array are printed unconditionally after this loop, hence *the loop does nothing*, it has no side effect, the loop index `i` would be meaningful after the end of the loop to determine if an entry has no match, but it is local to the loop.

Comment: @Mark: *Why is so difficult to understand? Do not look at the code, and come up with the fastest way to tackle it, is that hard?* You should tone down a little, the code does what it does, and as posted it does not solve your problem. If you want help solving the problem, it would be more productive to read comments and answers and address the issues raised instead of attacking benevolent contributors.

Comment: @Mark: You understand that your program always prints the contents of `C`, as you just wrote in the updated question. This is not consistent with the problem statement **"given two arrays.... print all the numbers from array C, only if each row of array d_D have at least one number in common with array C".** Your code is fast because the main loop has no side effects, so it can be optimized out, ie: the compiler generates no code for it. You are not benchmarking the algorithm, you are benchmarking the ability of the compiler to remove useless code.

Comment: Ok, lets try again, is consistent with the problem statement because each row of array d_D contains at least one number from array C, yes I made a mistake in code where the break  is, I rectified it, the point is not that the code print always the six numbers, the point is to find someone that can beat the time of the only part of the code that is important, the loop 1 to 50, that's it

Comment: The objective is not to look at my code to see if I made mistakes, but to come up with faster solution to the statement "given two arrays.... print all the numbers from array C, only if each row of array d_D have at least one number in common with array C"

Comment: it will now contribute https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/MIVMvDDJHw  , sorry for the typo: break instead of goto notfound;

Comment: Instead of saying: "Your code does not work: the for loop does nothing, so a good compiler will just remove it and the only thing you end up benchmarking is the initialization and the printf.", you should have said: "You loop works in itself, but the whole program not, but in order to benchmark it, you need to run it many times". And you were wrong again with: /* In the code posted, this line is always executed.
       Probably not the intended behavior.
       There is a missing test `if (i == ROWS)`
*/

Comment: , when the problem was the break instead of goto to a label that bypass the printf function.
However, regardless of that mistake, the loop is still executed and the compiler will never remove it. One could have said, ok this is the way I will do it, regardless of your code. I have never asked to solve my code, which anyway nobody did the correct way.

Comment: @Mark: I'm afraid you are incorrect. Benchmarking flawed code is meaningless. I added extra timings to show how the compiler **DOES** remove the dummy loop. You asked for help on how to optimize the code, it is important to first assert that the code is correct and second measure the inner loop and not ancillary code such as the initialisation loops and the `printf` statement. Your loop was correct, but the simple mistake on the `break;` statement made it ineffective. I posted another answer with actual improvements from a simple change in this loop. It may work or not on your target system.

Comment: I disagree, if you look at the link provided, here again: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/MIVMvDDJHw you will see that even when printf is not used because I changed the first array not to contain the common number, the loop will always executed, just look at the other printf, and if you want to be sure, put the break back. Is the loop that is important, not the printf and related code, if the compiler would remove the loop if will never printf "NOT FOUND 50 TIMES", Sorry enable it in the ide, now is commented out, printf "not found"

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking your updated code with separate timings for the initialization and scan time, I get this on OS/X:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Time elapsed in ms: 382.522000
Init time in ms: 317.204000
Scan time in ms: 65.237000
```

Note how the initialization phase takes most of the time, due to the numerous calls to `rand()`.

Transposing the tests, ie: comparing each element of each row in `d_C` with the 6 elements of `C` before trying the next one improves the scan time tremendously, by a factor of **5**:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Time elapsed in ms: 327.496000
Init time in ms: 315.463000
Scan time in ms: 11.970000
```

Alas, this is a side effect of the way you initialize the `d_C` array: the first element of each row is the matching one, so testing it first against all elements of `C` is way more efficient. If this strong bias is representative of your actual data, this method is definitely a better approach.

To remove this bias, I changed the initialization to set the matching element randomly and the timings are:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Time elapsed in ms: 447.353000
Init time in ms: 389.708000
Scan time in ms: 57.530000
```

The intialization takes a little longer, but the scan is 10% faster than the reference.

For completeness, here are the timings for this new set of data with the original code:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Time elapsed in ms: 427.428000
Init time in ms: 356.916000
Scan time in ms: 70.434000
```

When the matching element on each row of `d_C` is chosen randomly, the scan phase with the original code is 10% slower than with the biassed data. The overall improvement is therefore approximately **20%** with the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS  5000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    clock_t stop, stop1, stop2;

    int *d_D = (int*)malloc(ROWS * 6 * sizeof(int));
    int *C = (int*)malloc(1 * 6 * sizeof(int));

    C[0] = 1; C[1] = 2; C[2] = 3; C[3] = 4; C[4] = 5; C[5] = 6;

    // Put random numbers in the array d_D, but make sure
    // at least one element matches
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        unsigned int index = rand() % 6;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            d_D[i * 6 + j] = (j == index) ?
                (rand() % 6) + 1 : (rand() % ROWS) + 1;
        }
    }

    stop1 = clock();

#define OP ||  /* you can try changing the operator to | or + */

    int allfound = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[0]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[1]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[2]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[3]) OP
            (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[4]) OP (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[5])) {
            goto NextFilter;
        }
        allfound = 0;
        break;
    NextFilter:
        ;
    }
    stop2 = clock();
    if (allfound) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
               C[0 * 6 + 0], C[0 * 6 + 1], C[0 * 6 + 2],
               C[0 * 6 + 3], C[0 * 6 + 4], C[0 * 6 + 5]);
    }
    stop = clock();
    printf("Time elapsed in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Init time in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop1 - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Scan time in ms: %f\n", (double)(stop2 - stop1) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to run this benchmark on your target system to see if it shows the same improvements. Be aware that this type of micro-optimisation is highly dependant on the compiler version, settings and the target system hardware.

Comment: No, micro-optimisation does not work for me, you need to follow the latest code in the latest link provided, that is the best way to benchmark it, because no rows of array d_D will have a common number with array C, so all the if and or are executed. No change of i with ROWS, but 50 against 1 but run 50 millions times. Only the loop counts for me, not the initialization, not the printf and its correctness, just the execution of each number of array d_D against each number of array C, and some magic trick that can replace all that to improve performance.

Comment: Please note, that my complete code which is more complex of the one provided here, always worked under intel, arm, cuda and opencl, the code provided above was copy and pasted in a rush and that is why was full of mistakes, it was one of the many experiments I did.

Comment: This https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/UdmhvxBXjx shows that the loop works, I took out the printf, I put back the break, and it prints out 50 times "NOT FOUND", well, with the restriction imposed by the ide "Output Limit Exceeded", to make sure, you could do something like: if (i <= 20) printf("not found"); and you will see that the compiler will never take the loop out, even if the loop is useless.

Comment: sorry, I mean 50 millions times. Also I can confirm that swapping the way the arrays are compared results in longer executing time.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not do what you wrotet in the question. You need to iterate until first row does not contain. You do not check for this at all.

What is faster you need to benchmark yourself:

```
int foo1(int *d_D, int *C)
{
    int found = 1, all;
    for (size_t i = 0; found && i < 50; i++) 
    {
        all = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; !all && j < 6; j++) 
        {
            all = (d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[j]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[j]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[j]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[j]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[j]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[j]);
        }
    found = found && all;
    }    
    return found;
}

int foo(int *d_D, int *C)
{
    int found = 1, all;
    for (size_t i = 0; found && i < 50; i++) 
    {
        all = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; !all && j < 6; j++) 
        {
            for (size_t z = 0; !all && z < 6; z++) 
            {
                all = all || d_D[i * 6 + j] == C[z];
            }    
        }
    found = found && all;
    }    
    return found;
}

int AtLeastOneInAllRows(int *d_D, int *C)
{
    int found = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    {

        if ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[1]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[1]))
        {                         
            found = 1;
            continue;
        }


        if (!found && ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[2]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[2])))
        {
            found = 1;
            continue;                        
        }


        if (!found && ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[3]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[3])))
        {
            found = 1;
            continue;
        }


        if (!found && ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[4]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[4])))
        {
            found = 1;
            continue;
        }


        if (!found && ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[5]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[5])))
        {
            found = 1;
            continue;
        }


        if (!found && ((d_D[i * 6 + 0] == C[6]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 1] == C[6]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 2] == C[6]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 3] == C[6]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 4] == C[6]) || (d_D[i * 6 + 5] == C[6])))
        {
            found = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(!found) break;            
        }
        return found;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xckrMD

Comment: foo1 -> slower than mine, foo -> even slower than foo1, AtLeastOneInAllRows does work because return at least 1 true in 50, so it print the 6 numbers when it should not. Compiler: Icc, windows 7 x64, intel i7-5775C at 4.2 GHz

To make AtLeastOneInAllRows, found = 1 should be changed in found += 1 and than -> if (found == 50), which means slowest of them all.

Comment: yes the code I showed does what I wrote in the question and I made many many experiments resulting as that one being the fastest.

Comment: @Mark: I'm sorry to differ: the code posted always prints the contents of `C`. Why don't you post a full program that performs according to your goals? The fragment posted is misaligned, is hard to read due to overlong lines and a good compiler will just remove the whole `for` loop so I'm not surprised it is *fast* :)

Comment: @chqrlie: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/BEHy1x7yKX